# URLParameter is added to the endpoint every second during the data live fetch and endpoint becomes too big

Tags: swift, rest, urlsession

I'm working with a dynamic url that changes every time I add a new currencyPair. However, it's adding a new pair every time the apiTimer below is triggered and the url endpoint increases every one second. However, it should add only when a new currency pair is added to the MainTableViewController, not every once second.

Here's what I tried so far:

- Changed the endpoint: String on the func request() to endpoint: URLParameters.
- Changed the parameters of the function.
- Restructured the Timer function.

Any idea on what's the issue and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

```
import Foundation

class NetworkEngine {
    /// Executes the web call and will decode the JSON response into Codable object provided
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - endpoint: the endpoint to make the HTTP request against
    ///   - completion: the JSON response converted to the provided Codable object, if successful, or failure otherwise
    static let shared = NetworkEngine()

    func request<T: Codable>(_ endpoint: String, completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> ()) {

        guard let url = URL(string: endpoint) else {
            return
        }

        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
        print(urlRequest, "respponse2")


        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in

            guard error == nil else {
                completion(.failure(error!))
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")
                return
            }

            guard response != nil, let safeData = data else { return }


            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let responseObject = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: safeData) {
                    completion(.success(responseObject))
                } else {
                    let error = NSError(domain: "", code: 200, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "Failed to decode response"])
                    completion(.failure(error))
                    print(error)
                }

            }


        }

        dataTask.resume()
    }

}
```

```
 lazy var apiTimer: Timer = {
        var timer = Timer()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(urlFetch), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        return timer
    }()

 @objc fileprivate func urlFetch() {
        guard let endpoint = currencyPairModel.getUrlComponent().url?.absoluteString else { return }

        NetworkEngine.shared.request(endpoint) { [weak self] (result: Result<[String: Double], Error>) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let rateResults):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("TESTTTTT")
                    let cells = self?.currencyListTableView.visibleCells as! [CurrencyListTableViewCell]
                    for cell in cells {
                        print(cell,"cell")
                        print(cells,"cells")
                        for key in rateResults.keys {
                            if key == cell.currencyPair.currencyPairKey {
                                print(key,"key")
                                cell.currencyPair.addRate(rateResults)
                                print(rateResults,"rateResults")
                                print(rateResults.keys,"rateResults.keys")
                                self?.currencyListTableView.beginUpdates()
                                cell.rate = cell.currencyPair?.getRate()
                                self?.currencyListTableView.endUpdates()

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                self?.showAlert(with: "Error!", message: error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

```
mutating func getUrlComponent() -> URLComponents {

        for currencyPair in currencyPairs {
            let param = URLQueryItem(name: "pairs", value: currencyPair.currencyPairKey)
            components.queryItems?.append(param)
        }

        return components
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. You call `getUrlComponent()` method every second. In this method you are getting the existing components, appending query items for pairs and save the components in instance variable. That is why your url is growing every second. Just clear the query items array in the beginning of the method.

```
mutating func getUrlComponent() -> URLComponents {
    components.queryItems = []
    for currencyPair in currencyPairs {
        let param = URLQueryItem(name: "pairs", value: currencyPair.currencyPairKey)
        components.queryItems?.append(param)
    }

    return components
}
```

And is it ok, that you have several query items with the same name `pairs`?

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't notice this detail. It's working fine now. Yes, it is. It's a json Dictionary:  [String: Double] with the key pairs